# How to clean a list of strings

Tags: python, string, data-cleaning

I´m trying to clean the following data:

```
from sklearn import datasets

data = datasets.fetch_20newsgroups(categories=['rec.autos', 'rec.sport.baseball', 'soc.religion.christian'])
texts, targets = data['data'], data['target']
```

Where `texts` is a list of articles and `targets` is a vector containing the index of the category to which each article belongs to.

I need to clean all articles. The cleaning task means:

- Remove headers
- Remove punctuation
- Remove parenthesis
- Consecutive blank spaces
- Tokens emails with length 1
- Line breaks

I'm quite new at Python but I've tried to remove all punctuation and everything using replace(). However, I think that an easy way to do this task must exist.

```
def clean_articles (article):
    return ' '.join([x for x in article[article.find('\n\n'):].replace('.','').replace('[','')

clean_articles(data['data'][1])
```

For the following article:

```
print(data['data'][1])
```

### Uncleaned Article:

'From: aas7@po.CWRU.Edu (Andrew A. Spencer)\nSubject: Re: Too fast\nOrganization: Case Western Reserve University, Cleveland, OH (USA)\nLines: 25\nReply-To: aas7@po.CWRU.Edu (Andrew A. Spencer)\nNNTP-Posting-Host: slc5.ins.cwru.edu\n\n\nIn a previous article, wrat@unisql.UUCP (wharfie) says:\n\n>In article <1qkon8$3re@armory.centerline.com> jimf@centerline.com (Jim Frost) writes:\n>>larger engine.  That\'s what the SHO is -- a slightly modified family\n>>sedan with a powerful engine.  They didn\'t even bother improving the\n>>*brakes.*\n>\n>\tThat shows how much you know about anything.  The brakes on the\n>SHO are very different - 9 inch (or 9.5? I forget) discs all around,\n>vented in front.  The normal Taurus setup is (smaller) discs front, \n>drums rear.\n\none i saw had vented rears too...it was on a lot.\nof course, the sales man was a fool..."titanium wheels"..yeah, right..\nthen later told me they were "magnesium"..more believable, but still\ncrap, since Al is so m uch cheaper, and just as good....\n\n\ni tend to agree, tho that this still doesn\'t take the SHO up to "standard"\nfor running 130 on a regular basis.  The brakes should be bigger, like\n11" or so...take a look at the  ones on the Corrados.(where they have\nbraking regulations).\n\nDREW\n'

### Cleaned Article:

In previous article UUCP wharfie says In article centerline com com Jim Frost writes larger engine That's what the SHO is slightly modified family sedan with powerful engine They didn't even bother improving the *brakes That shows how much you know about anything The brakes on the SHO are very different inch or forget discs all around vented in front The normal Taurus setup is smaller discs front drums rear one saw had vented rears too it was on lot of course the sales man was fool titanium wheels yeah right then later told me they were magnesium more believable but still crap since Al is so uch cheaper and just as good tend to agree tho that this still doesn't take the SHO up to standard for running 130 on regular basis The brakes should be bigger like 11 or so take look at the ones on the Corrados where they have braking regulations DREW

Comment: This question is overly broad and there are many questions on SO dealing with cleaning text.  The set contains 1790 articles with varying conditions that you'll need to clean. Removing punctuation and whitespace is easy, but you'll also need to remove the extra information before the article text.  Additionally, you'll need to remove html tags in the text and email addresses.

Comment: Search SO with [python][string] clean

Answer (score 0):

note: this is not a complete answer, but the following will at least get you half way to:

- remove punctuation
- remove line breaks
- remove consecutive white space
- remove parentheses

```py
import re
s = ';\n(a    b.,'
print('before:', s)
s = re.sub('[.,;\n(){}\[\]]', '', s)
s = re.sub('\s+', ' ', s)
print('after:', s)
```

this will print:

```
before: ;
(a    b.,
after: a b
```

Comment: Thank you @randomfigure, however, it is not working. I get the following error:  'str' object has no attribute 're'